# executing shell command from ruby

Tags: ruby

This isn't working in ruby and I don't understand why?

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

exec "sort data.txt > data.sort"
```

data.txt is a comma sepparated file. Anyway.. If I try to execute that line in the shell it works without a problem.

When I try to run this script from my script, I get an empty file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really an answer, but I wanted to share that your original usage of exec is actually working for me.  This was how I set it up.

data.txt

```
"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8"
```

sort.rb (I don't know what your sort did so I am just writing the same data out)

```
File.open(ARGV[0]){|f| puts f.read}
```

irb session

```
irb(main):001:0> exec "sort data.txt > data.sort"
```

When I ran this in irb, I did get a data.sort output file and it contained "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8" as expected.  I can run the same exec line through irb or from another ruby file, and I get the output file with data each time.

I am running Ruby 1.8.6 on a 32bit Windows XP system.

Comment: Oh.. I think I know what's happening... I actually write the file myself in a few lines above it. file = File.new("data.txt", "w") and then it probably has not flushed that to disk.. and so when it actually executes the command there is nothing to sort. How do I flush to disk?

Comment: Ah.. I need to close the file file.close

Comment: Thank anyway, I figure out things by discussing them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
%x(sort data.txt > data.sort)
```

Comment: I just tried that it didn't work.. I substitute the exec line with yours right?

Comment: Oh.. I think I now know what's happening... I actually write the file myself in a few lines above it. file = File.new("data.txt", "w") and then it probably has not flushed that to disk.. and so when it actually executes the command there is nothing to sort. How do I flush to disk? – Ted Flethuseo 8 mins ago 
Ah.. I need to close the file file.close